# Need unix command to disable the popup window

Tags: shell

I am very much glad if anyone help me. am fairly new to Unix scripting side. I am trying to get into one url, but before that am getting one popup window(asking for customer details). So, i need to block/disable/ auto close the popup window. Please help me with the command

Comment: > url, popups, browsers
> unix scripting

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

In Unix environment `shell` command plays differently. It can launch your browser but it can not set utility inside a browser application. You need to fix it inside your browser window by using `tool` option. Just search in google like `how to block popup in yourbrowserName`.